# Multiple link columns for a report in Application Express?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

Is it possible  to create additional Link Columns in an interactive report? I mean, I have a table of users, but I want to have two link columns, one of which would open a page that lets me edit, and another link to just open the details.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create an Interactive Report, you can provide the first link when you specify the sql for the query, this is the link to the single row view of the IR.

Standard, you start with this one column on the IR, and you can find the details of this link column in the Report Attributes > Link Column. Note that only here you can select the option 'Link to Single Row View'.

[image: report link column]

If you want extra link columns, you will have to edit your query (edit report). For example:

```
select empno, ename, job, sal, null link_column1, null link_column2
from emp
```

This way, i generate 2 extra columns for the report, whose value is always null (however, this is not a requirement! You could just aswell select 'ename link_column1' as an extra column - handy to use as link text).

To turn these columns into link columns (or any other column actually!), you have to go to the column edit page: either via the report attributes, and clicking the edit link next to the column, or in the tree view by rightclicking on the column and choosing edit.

[image: column attributes 1]
[image: column attributes 2]

On the edit page, scroll down to the Column Link section. Here you can set up the link to another page once more.
[image: column link section]

Once done, you can verify the link columns in your reports attributes.
[image: verify col link]

Finally, don't forget to add the columns to your interactive report! Since you most likely add these afterward, you need to go the actions menu, choose select columns, and add the extra columns. Don't forget to save as primary if you mean this to be your default view.

[image: final view]